# Calculating True Prevalence (when apparent prevalence estimates are too low or too high) - avoiding negative values in CIs or values >100%

Tags: r

The truePrev () function from the prevalence package works well when supplied with single values of x and n; but fails when supplied with numeric vectors. How can i possibly compute true prevalence estimates for vectors of length >1 .

eg: this works well

```
library(prevalence)
truePrev(x = 142, n = 742, SE = 0.949, SP = 0.994)
```

but when I assign numeric vectors to x and n, it returns an error:

```
truePrev(x = c(142,149, 06), n = c(742,742,742), SE = 0.90, SP = 0.90)
```

> "Error in if (!binom & sum(x) != n) stop("'x' does not sum to 'n'") :
> the condition has length > 1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that the function you are using is not vectorized. So you will have to loop over the values and run the function for each set of values, i.e.

```
v1 <- c(142, 149, 6)
v2 <- c(742, 742, 742)

mapply(function(x, n) {
  truePrev(x = x, n = n, SE = 0.90, SP = 0.90)
}, v1, v2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns the same error

Comment: @user22295101 try the edited version. There was a minor typo.